# ClassNotFoundException with Guice 2.0

Tags: java, guice, classnotfoundexception

The code below generates an error using Guice 2.0. With Guice 1.0 everything is fine. The JDK is Java 6 update 15.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                // just testing 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:78)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:232)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at App.main(App.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 14 more
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have missed to include a [dependency jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/) with the class `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor` in the classpath.

Comment: typical case of RTFM I guess. Thx!!

Answer (score 6):

as [Boris Pavlović](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266587/error-with-guice-2-0#1266786) mentions in his answer, you're missing a jar. Specifically the aopalliance.jar file, which comes in the guice [zip file](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/files/guice-2.0.zip)

Alternatively, you might try using [guice-2.0-no_aop.jar](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/files/guice-2.0-no_aop.jar), but I'm not sure if that will work.

Adding this file to the classpath depends on which tool you use to run your java code.

- If you are running java from the command line:

> ```
> windows: java -cp aopalliance.jar;guice-2.0.jar;other_jars.jar YourMainClass
> *nix:    java -cp aopalliance.jar:guice-2.0.jar:other_jars.jar YourMainClass
> ```

- If you are running java from Eclipse,
  typically you'll have some type of
  lib/ directory. Put your jar there,
  then right-click on the jar -> Build
  Path -> Add to Build Path

Answer (score 2):

I run into this problem yesterday, the dependency is managed by Maven, so the aopalliance.jar is in classpath with no doubt.

Update jetty from version 6.1.10 to 6.1.26 fixed the problem.

The real problem here is the container does not support aopalliance.jar. I hope that will help someone there desperately looking for a solution.

Comment: I'm using 6.1.26 and still getting the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem today. Actually the tomcat can not find the class in its lib. So just copy the aopalliance.jar into the lib folder in tomcat ,that's enough.

Answer (score -2):

Adding the below jars works fine for me.
**javax.inject.jar** 
***guice-3.0-no_aop.jar***