# Why am I getting a ClassNotFoundException with Guice 2.0 on Android?

Tags: android, guice

I created a new Android project, using Guice to inject a class; But when I run it, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

The Exception happened after I updated the Android plugin to the latest version in Eclipse，

Version:
jdk-6u33-windows-x64

guice-2.0-no_aop

Android 2.1

---

Code:

```
public class TextApplication{>....
        public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;

        this.in = Guice.createInjector(new BaseModule()); //Exception happens
        ........
        }


public class BaseModule implements Module {

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(ServiceRequest.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);     
        binder.bind(TService.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        .......
    }

}
```

---

Log:

```
08-02 16:28:26.646: E/dalvikvm(18212): Could not find class
 '[Lcom.google.inject.Module;', referenced from method
 com.shuyou.shop.TextApplication.onCreate 08-02 16:28:26.656:
 W/dalvikvm(18212): VFY: unable to resolve new-array 588
 ([Lcom/google/inject/Module;) in Lcom/shuyou/shop/TextApplication;
 08-02 16:28:26.656: W/dalvikvm(18212): threadid=1: thread exiting with
 uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc8a0) 08-02 16:28:26.666:
 E/AndroidRuntime(18212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-02 16:28:26.666:
 E/AndroidRuntime(18212): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 [Lcom.google.inject.Module; 08-02 16:28:26.666:
 E/AndroidRuntime(18212):   at
 com.shuyou.shop.TextApplication.onCreate(TextApplication.java:27)
 08-02 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):   at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
 08-02 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4286)
 08-02 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:132) 08-02
 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109)
 08-02 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):   at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-02
 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 08-02 16:28:26.666:
  E/AndroidRuntime(18212):  at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669) 08-02
 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-02
 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 08-02 16:28:26.666:
 E/AndroidRuntime(18212):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
 08-02 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634) 08-02
 16:28:26.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18212):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

`BaseModule` should `extend AbstractModule` not `implement Module`.

Comment: i did, but it doest't work. = =||||

Comment: @karen `BaseModule` should `extend AbstractModule` not `implement Module`.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[ClassNotFoundException with Guice 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266587/classnotfoundexception-with-guice-2-0)

It seems you're missing a JAR in your project.

[Download:](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check that you have correctly added the required jar to your buildpath.